# Problem using "\" in cd command via local-exec in Terraform on Windows

Tags: terraform

A co-worker created a Terraform script on his Mac and wanted me to test it.  The problem I have is with this line in his script:

```
provisioner "local-exec" {
  command = "cd '../Azure Functions/ewxpws_datacollect'; func azure functionapp publish ${azurerm_linux_function_app.data_collector.name}"}
```

If I run the script as is in Windows, I get:

```
Error running command 'cd '../Azure Functions/ewxpws_datacollect'; func azure functionapp publish fn-ewxpws-devx': exit status 1. Output: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I also get the same thing if I replace forward slash with escaped backslashes.  Is there some way to modify this line so that it works on Windows and Mac?

Comment: Try using `working_dir` instead of using `cd`: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec#working_dir.

Comment: That did the trick.  Thanks for helping out this Terraform newb!

Comment: Although `working_dir` would be more reliable, the way to fix this use of `cd` would be to `cd '../Azure Functions/ewxpws_datacollect' && func azure functionapp publish ${azurerm_linux_function_app.data_collector.name`. `working_dir` is still better though. @MarkoE --> answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to [Marko E](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8343484/marko-e), whose [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74070088/problem-using-in-cd-command-via-local-exec-in-terraform-on-windows/74070476#comment130778463_74070088)

> Try using `working_dir` instead of using `cd`: [developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/…](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec#working_dir).

provided the answer: I needed to supply a `working_dir` option to the provisioner.